# tensorflow multiple readers 1 file

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

Regarding using tensorflow 0.9 in a fully connected setting, I thought I read about some (possibly contrib) code to allow multiple readers on a single file, but I can't for the life of me find it.

I am familiar with [slim parallel_reader](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2a06837336bc29cb797c5be5605cb6188857768c/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data/parallel_reader.py), but my understanding so far is that it uses 1 reader per filename (or per file in filename queue).

Comment: I think regular reader does what you need. You can see in parallel_reader there's nothing preventing you from having multiple filenames refer to the same file

Comment: Yaroslav, thanks for the help. I do not see any support in TFRecordReader to indicate number of threads. Are you suggesting listing the same file multiple times to TFRecordReader?

Comment: It uses just one thread. If you have two "run" calls in parallel on the same record reader op, it'll run these two ops in parallel. But there may be a lock that will prevent concurrency in that case, not sure. However, you can create two TFRecordReader ops with the same filename, this way there'll be no locking for sure

Comment: Do you mean along these lines?...filename_queue=string_input_producer(..); ser1= reader1.read(filename_queue); ser2= reader2.read(filename_queue). fea1= parse(ser1) fea2=parse(ser1). batch=batch_join([fea1,fea2])